# How to create JwtProcessor from hardcoded JSON

Tags: kotlin, jwt

How can I create a jwtProcessor from a hardcoded jwk JSON. `JWSVerificationKeySelector` is expecting a jwkSource.

```
fun createJwtProcessor(): DefaultJWTProcessor<SecurityContext> {
    // Replace with your hardcoded JWK JSON string
    val jwkJson = """
        {
            "kty": "RSA",
            "n": "your-modulus-value",
            "e": "your-exponent-value"
            // Other JWK parameters...
        }
    """.trimIndent()

    val rsaKey = RSAKey.parse(jwkJson)

    val jwtProcessor = DefaultJWTProcessor<SecurityContext>()
    jwtProcessor.jwsKeySelector = JWSVerificationKeySelector(JWSAlgorithm.Family.RSA, rsaKey.toRSAPublicKey()) //compilation error
    return jwtProcessor
  }
```